# Create email (outlook format) on web-service side (Java) and send to front end and download

Tags: java, angular

I want to write a service through which I can create a email message with (to, cc, bcc, subject, body) specified. Then I need to return this email message to front end and download it in ".oft" format, in such a way that when I click on this downloaded file; file should open with all the fields (to, cc, bcc, subject, body) populated.

I am using Java as backend technology and angular5 as front-end.

I have tried using javax.mail utility to create the email message and return it as byte array. Something like:

```
Properties prop = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("emailAddr@domain.com"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("emailAddr@domain.com"));
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setSubject("subject");
msg.setText("text of msg"); 


//return it from service API as
response.getOutputStream().write(msg.toString().getBytes());
```

On front end (component.ts file) I am retrieving the response as :

```
//function gets called on button click
createEmailTemplate():void{
    this.httpService.getEmail('serviceUrl')
    .subscribe(
      email => {
         let filename = "SampleMailFile.oft";
         let linkElement = document.createElement('a');
         let blob = new Blob([email], { type: "message/rfc822"});
         let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
         linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
         linkElement.setAttribute("download", filename);
         let clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                "view": window,
                 "bubbles": true,
                 "cancelable": false
          });
         linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
      }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A MSG file is supposed to have the same format as an OFT file. If that’s true then you should be able to use [jotlmsg](https://github.com/ctabin/jotlmsg) to generate the file. You shouldn’t need to use JavaMail at all for this, since it’s intended to actually send the mail.

**NOTE:** I’ve not used this library before, so I can’t speak to whether this will truly work.